# Separation of perturbative and non-perturbative contributions in partition function computation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, perturbation-theory, partition-function, non-perturbative

The following is defined, where $\epsilon \to 0^+$ is a cutoff:
$$ \mathcal{F}(Z)=\int_{\epsilon}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{s}
\frac{1}{\sinh^2 s/2} e^{-sx}. $$

Question: how do we see that $\mathcal{F}$ has a
perturbative + non-perturbative expansion (in $x \gg 0$) given by

$$ \mathcal{F}(Z) = \sum_g \mathcal{F}_g x^{2-2g} + O(e^{-x}),$$
for some coefficients $\mathcal{F}_g$ ?

Reference: the issue is discussed in [arXiv:hep-th/9809187](http://arXiv.org/abs/hep-th/9809187) eq. (3.2) and below. The book *Quantum Field Theory* by Itzykson and Zuber eq. (4-117) and below should help clarify.

It should be possible to see this kind of expansion by rescaling the variable $s$ in the integral and making a Taylor expansion of the $\sinh^2$ in the denominator. The non-perturbative terms should arise from picking up poles at imaginary values of $s= 2\pi i n.$

Note that the $\epsilon$ parameter is supposed to ensure convergence of the integral.

---

I think I found a partial answer in the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4082 paragraphs 2.2 and 2.4, although I'm not 100% sure how one relates formula (2.20) here with (2.1) in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9812127

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can simplify this by rewriting it as an indefinite integral of $x = Z/F$ like so:
\begin{equation}
\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{ds}{s^3} \left ( \frac{s/2}{\sinh s/2} \right )^2 e^{-s x} = - \frac{1}{4}  \int_\epsilon^\infty ds \int_0^x dx \frac{1}{\sinh^2 s/2} e^{-s x}
\end{equation}

From here, you have roughly
\begin{equation}
\int_\epsilon^\infty ds \int_0^x dx \frac{e^{-s}}{(1 - e^{-s} )^2} e^{-s x}
\end{equation}
and the fraction can be Taylor expanded and the integrals evaluated order by order. I believe that's how that would work.

Comment: I'm sorry, that limit of integration should be from $x$ to $\infty$.

Comment: what you get is $-\int_{\epsilon}^\infty \mathrm{d}s \int_x^\infty \mathrm{d}m \frac{e^{-s}}{(1-e^{-s})^2}e^{-sm}$: are you suggesting to expand near $s=\infty$ the fraction $\frac{e^{-s}}{(1-e^{-s})^2}$ ?

Comment: Because then, I'm not sure how to proceed to obtain the two contributions above

Comment: $1/(1 - x)^2 = \frac{d}{d x} \sum_n x^n$ which is more or less the form you have for $x = e^{-s}$ and since $s > 0$ the series will converge. Then you have an infinite series of exponentials and you can integrate them that way.

Comment: OK, but have you been able to reproduce the above result in this way?

Comment: in particular, where does the non-perturbative part comes from?

Comment: What non-perturbative part? The $\mathcal{O}(e^{-Z/F})$?

Comment: yes, i was asking where that piece comes from in your computation

Comment: I will sit down and write it up, and post the resulting note probably this weekend. Stand by.

Comment: is it possible computing the integral by looking at poles of the denominator and apply residue theory?